# trying to prevent ddos with cisco pix 501

Tags: cisco, ddos, cisco-pix

I'm getting dos on a dedicated server with windows+apache, ive asked support to install a firewall and got a cisco pix 501, the attacks are on port 80 to a certain site, what can I do to block it?

I thought of putting a cap on amount of connections
Disallowing access for certain ip ranges (the attackers use mainly ukraine and india)

Any ideas?

more than that, how do I do it with the cisco? any command lines would help

Answer (score 4):

They gave you a pix 501 to stop a DDoS ? outch sorry but that's a crappy old SOHO class firewall it will probably make things worse. Tell them to filter the traffic upstream of your connection

Comment: Indeed. Especially since the PIX line is officially dead and has published compromisable vulnerabilities available.